# How can i manually determine the most general types for the following functions?

Tags: haskell, types, lambda, currying

Currently I am learning Haskell. We have to determine the most general types for given functions, but I do not get it yet. How does the interpreter determine the most general type of the function, especially lambda expressions? What is a secure way to determine the most general type manually?

```
tx2 = (\x y z -> y.z.z)

tx2::a->(a->b)->(a->a)->b -- my guess

tx2 :: a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> b -> c -- interpreter solution
```

If the first variable (a) is applied to expression z, then z must take a as an input parameter, but it consumes b instead in (b->b). y consumes b and generates c, so the final result must be c. But why is b (as intermediate result?) contained in the type? And if so, why is it not a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> b-> b -> c ?

```
tm2 = (\i -> [sum,product]!!i)

tm2:: Int->[(Integer->Integer->Integer)]->(Integer->Integer->Integer) -- my guess

\i -> [sum,product] !! i :: Num a => Int -> [a] -> a -- interpreter with direct input
tm2 :: Int -> [Integer] -> Integer -- interpreter with :info tm2
```

So the interpreter has more detailed information about the type if tm2 is in coded in the script, right? So the type in the second line is the result of the expression. Why are only Integers accepted in line 2, not Float for example?

```
tp2 = (\x -> \y -> (x.y.x))

tp2::(a->b)->((a->b)->a)->a -- my guess

tp2 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> a -> b -- interpreter solution
```

Why do I have to include the intermediate result a here in the type? Why is \y not represented using (a->b)->a like in tf2 below?

```
tf2 = (\x -> \y -> (x (y x), x, y))

tf2::(a->b)->((a->b)->a)->(a,a->b,(a->b)->a) -- solution


tg2 = (\x y z a -> y(z(z(a))));

tg2::a->(b->c)->(b->b)->b->c -- solution
```

Here we do not need any intermediate results? We write down the types of the params and then the type of the result?

Comment: That's a lot of questions! That doesn't make it easy to answer, so I won't - but from your last examples (`tp2` and `tf2`) you seem to be assuming that `x.y.x` and `x (y x)` are the same, but they're not! Also, I suspect you've made a typo in `tx2`...

Comment: Ahh so you mean that (.) :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b is a specified operation which has something like an intermediate result, while an expression like x (y x) is of type a -> a . Thx, this is already the answer to one problem.

Comment: @Blackbam: actually `(.)` is simply the composition, i.e. `(f . g) x = f ( g x )`.

Comment: So (x.y.x) a would be the same as x(y(x a))) ? But this still does not explain the typing here..

Comment: Yes, it is. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
tx2 = (\x y z -> y.z.z)
```

`tx2` takes three arguments (for the sake of discussion, I ignore currying), ignores the first and composes the second and twice the third. So the first argument can have any type, the second and third must have function type, say

```
y :: ay -> ry
z :: az -> rz
```

Now the result of the first application of `z` becomes the argument of the second application of `z`, so the result type of `z`, `rz` must be the argument type of `z`, `az`, let us call that `b`, so

```
z :: b -> b
```

Then the result of the `z` application becomes the argument of `y`, so the argument type of `y` must be the same type as the result type of `z`, but the result type of `y` is completely unconstrained by the expression, hence

```
y :: b -> c
```

and `y . z . z :: b -> c`, thus

```
tx2 :: a -> (b -> c) -> (b -> b) -> (b -> c)
```

Then the next,

```
tm2 = (\i -> [sum,product]!!i)
```

Now, `sum` and `product` are functions from the `Prelude`, both have the type `Num a => [a] -> a`, thus

```
Prelude> :t [sum,product]
[sum,product] :: Num a => [[a] -> a]
```

Since `(!!) :: [e] -> Int -> e`, given a list `xs` of type `[e]`, the expression `\i -> xs !! i` has type `Int -> e`. Thus the inferred type of `tm2 = \i -> [sum,product] !! i` is

```
tm2 :: Num a => Int -> ([a] -> a)
```

But, `tm2` is bound by a simple pattern binding without type signature, so the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5) kicks in, and the type of `tm2` has to be monomorphised. By the defaulting rules, a `Num a` constraint is resolved by instantiating the type variable `a` with `Integer` (unless an explicit default declaration says otherwise), so you get

```
Prelude> let tm2 = \i -> [sum,product] !! i
Prelude> :t tm2
tm2 :: Int -> [Integer] -> Integer
```

unless you disable the monomorphism restriction (`:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`).

```
tp2 = (\x -> \y -> (x.y.x))
```

The result of the first application of `x` becomes the argument of `y`, hence the result type of `x` must be the same as the argument type of `y`. Then the result of the application of `y` becomes the argument of the second application of `x`, so the result type of `y` must be the argument type of ´x`, altogether

```
tp2 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> (a -> b)
```

Then in

```
tf2 = (\x -> \y -> (x (y x), x, y))
```

the only interesting part is the first component of the result, `x (y x)`, so `x` is applied to the result of an application of `y`, hence `x` must have a function type

```
x :: a -> b
```

and `y` must have result type `a`. But `y` is applied to `x`, so its argument type must be the type of `x`,

```
y :: (a -> b) -> a
```

and

```
tf2 :: (a -> b) -> ((a -> b) -> a) -> (b, a -> b, (a -> b) -> a)
```

Finally

```
tg2 = (\x y z a -> y(z(z(a))))
```

which is, by the way, exactly the same as `tx2`, only eta-expanded by providing one more argument in the lambda. Therefore the derivation of the type is the same too.

Answer (score 1):

I think many of your doubts about function types in Haskell would get an answer by reading something about "currying", on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) for example.

The inferred types of the functions you wrote are like that because Haskell works with curried functions, i.e. functions with only an input parameter that may return (depending on the definition) other functions.
So, when you write a function like `mySum x y = x + y` its type is `a -> a -> a`, more easily read by making explicit the right associativity of `->`: `a -> (a -> a)`. See? The extra return types you get aren't "intermediate results" as you call them.
You do not take two parameters and return the result, an `a`. You take one parameter, `x`, fix its value in the expression `x + y`, and return the function `a -> a` that takes a parameter (`y` this time) and sums it to the `y` you previously fixed.

Answering point by point to your question would be kinda long so I'll pass, but this is the reasoning you have to do in order to check for the types of your functions.

I'm not sure about difference between the inferred types by the interpreter for your second question on `tm2`.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer, I will do some more research about currying. If there are no more answers, I will accept this answer soon. Maybe somebody knows about the tm2 issue? Interpreter is Hugs 2006 (Haskell 98)

Comment: @Blackbam Didn't see that you use Hugs while writing my answer. The way to disable the MR I gave was for ghci. I'm not entirely sure what extensions the `-98` flag in hugs enables, so `hugs -98` may or may not disable the MR. Anyway, the last release of hugs is very old by now, and there is a new language standard. I recommend going with the times and using ghci (also, it is faster than hugs and comes with a full-blown compiler).